# Searching for Ubuntu video I saw that covered Ubuntu One

Tags: video

I have been searching for an Ubuntu video I saw 1-2 months ago where they guy was demonstrating Ubuntu One and how he used it to sync local profile stuff across different machines. Has anyone seen this? I forgot exactly what it was about but I know he spent a minute or two on the video if not the whole video.

I searched all my web history as well as youtube history but no go. Not sure if we are allowed to ask these questions but here goes.

Comment: Best bet is to ask a specific Ubuntu One question here, or try searching YouTube and filter the search results by 'upload date'. Your question is a bit vague and may be closed, but I hope the comment helps anyways.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.youtube.com/user/myubuntuone perhaps is the channel you're looking for?